# Is there a better syntax for subsetting a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to conditionally subset a dataframe *without* referencing the dataframe.  For example if I have the following:

```
long_data_frame_name <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
```

I want to say:

```
subset <- long_data_frame_name[x < 5,]
```

But instead, I have to say:

```
subset <- long_data_frame_name[long_data_frame_name$x < 5,]
```

plyr and ggplot handle this so beautifully.  Is there any package that makes subsetting a data frame similarly beautiful?

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. :-)  You may find `with` more lovely.

Comment: @Carl I don't see how `with` would apply in this case. That being said, though, I think it's hard to write beautiful R code without using `with` and `within`.

Comment: @Roman How so? You'd still have to type the name of the `data.frame` twice.

Comment: I agree with @mplourde: with `with`, you would still need `subset <- with(long_data_frame,long_data_frame_name[x < 5,])`, which doesn't save much (it only becomes useful if you have a bunch of conditions to subset on) -- unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, you're right.  I was trying :-( to extend my snarky comment about the subjectivity of "attractive" code.  I'd go with `subset` myself.

Comment: Bah, foiled by my cursory reading. With will not help you from not typing the name twice, of course...

Comment: Per beauty, I gave context for my standard of beauty with an example and an allusion to plyr and ggplot.  Subjective and clearly defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the **data.table** package, which implements indexing syntax just like that which you describe. (`data.table` objects are essentially `data.frame`s with added functionality, so you can continue to use them almost anywhere you would use a "plain old" data.frame.)

Matthew Dowle, the package's author, argues for the advantages of `[.data.table()`'s indexing syntax in his answer to [this popular SO [r]-tag question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r). His answer there could just as well have been written as a direct response to your question above!

Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)
long_data_table_name <- data.table(x=1:10, y=1:10) 

subset <- long_data_table_name[x < 5, ]
subset
#    x y
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 2
# 3: 3 3
# 4: 4 4
```

Comment: @Ben Be advised that `data.table`s and `data.frame`s aren't completely interchangeable. Additionally, I'm not sure I see the point of loading a extra library just for a syntax convention that the base language effectively supports.

Comment: @mplourde good warning.  I think subset seems like a safer option.  But clean syntax is important to me.  Its the reason I prefer python.  Its easier to read and therefore easier to comprehend.

Comment: @mplourde -- Thanks for adding this caveat, with which I totally agree. I'd probably have hedged more had Ben not specifically asked for "a package that makes subsetting a data.frame similarly beautiful".

Comment: @BenHaley -- And also be aware that `subset()` has its own shortcomings. In particular, do not try to use it programatically (i.e. within any functions you write); it's basically for interactive use, and there's even a Warning to that effect in `?subset`.

Comment: @Josh I believe the warning, because it's there. But I can't for the life of me come up with a scenario where it breaks...

Comment: @mplourde -- [Here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) with much discussion (and links to other examples) that should help you see the problem. (FWIW, it wasn't until *years* after I first read warning that I finally "got" what the problem with `subset()` was.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
newdata <- subset(mydata, sex=="m" & age > 25)
```

or

```
newdata <- subset(mydata, sex=="m" & age > 25 , select=weight:income)
```

Reference:
http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: 'subset <- subset(long_data_frame_name, sex < 5)' is very nice.  A little wordier than 'subset <- long_data_table_name[x < 5, ]', but I think its less likely to confuse people unfamiliar with data.table.

Answer (score 4):

Beauty is subjective, isn't it? In the interest of sharing other solutions, there's also the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
subset <- sqldf("select * from long_data_frame_name where x < 5")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try dplyr, released after this question was posted and answered. It is great for many common data frame munging tasks.

```
library(dplyr)
subset <- filter(long_data_frame_name, x > 5)
```

or, equivalently:

```
subset <- long_data_frame_name %>% filter(x > 5)
```